# Method of undetermined coefficients: particular solutions to forcing functions with negative degree polynomials?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on a DE with a "forcing" term on the RHS of $x^{-1/2}$. What should my particular solution look like? I'm guessing that since particular solutions look like
\begin{align}
x^2+x+1\implies Ax^2+Bx+C,
\end{align}
for typical polynomials it might just be
\begin{align}
x^{-1/2}\implies Ax^{-1/2}+B ?
\end{align}
But this feels completely wrong and as though it would not capture everything I would need to.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Have you considered using variation of parameters instead?

Comment: @littleO No, the textbook I am studying from told me to solve it using the MUC.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the full differential equation. Have you tried your guess to see if it works?